# Why does UIImagePickerController ignore the videoQuality property?

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I've tried using `UIImagePickerController` to record videos using `videoQuality` set to `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeHigh` and also set to `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType.TypeLow`. I've set the maximum duration to 2 seconds and have the phone laying down flat to control for variations in input.

No matter the `videoQuality`, the end result is withing 100k of 6.5MB in size. I expected the `.TypeLow` setting to provide significant space savings.

This is on an iPhone 6 running iOS 8.3.

Why does `UIImagePickerController` ignore the `videoQuality` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Settings > Photos & Camera > Record Video at 60 FPS` is enabled, it causes `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` to ignore `videoQuality`. I haven't found any documentation on this behavior, so it may just be a bug in iOS 8.3.